# Different Fontsize and Linespacing for document

Tags: fonts, line-spacing

So here it goes once again:

I am currently using this template [link](https://github.com/johannesbottcher/MDT-Quick-Manual)

What I want to do is to have different linespacing and fontsize settings for the title page and the main document

The title page should be 11pt and singlelinespacing and the main document should be 12pt and onehalfspacing.

What i have tried is to use `\setlinespace{1.5}` for each chapter, but this doesn't work.

**------Edit------**

I should also add the document class is BOOK, so in theory fontsize and linespacing for the titlepage should be 11pt and singlelinespacing

And additionally the chapters should be 12pt and onehalfspacing it that makes it clearer.

Comment: Please post a complete minimal example here: your question shouldn't depend on an external link as it becomes useless if the link content changes. Moreover, people are less likely to try helping you if they have to click through for code - especially since you've used the toxic term 'template'. Why do you say that 'in theory fontsize and linespacing for the titlepage should be 11pt and singlelinespacing' because the class is `book`? Basically, set what you want for the body of the document e.g. `12pt` as a class option. Then use `setspace` to get one-half spacing. Then do the titlepage.

Comment: I kind of got it working now but it's ugly (codewise) by inserting `\fontsize{11pt}{12}` into the title page enviroment, setting `\documentclass[12pt,\singlelinespace]` and then before I include the chapters adding `\onehalfspacing`. As I said it kind of does what i want, but I also think that there could be a more elegant way to write this

Comment: Just do the titlepage standalone and include it -> https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Title_Creation